# How to display only SINGLE minimum record from SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got small problem when creating my SQL statement for web app.

I've got a table with to_do_list (id, duration, text) and I want to display only ONE minimum record (where Duration = minimum), even if there are more than one.

I had created smth like this:

```
Select * from to_do_list where duration = (select min(duration) from to_do_list);
```

But it displays more than one record (I have few entrys with the same duration).

I tried also this one:

```
Select id, min(duration), text from to_do_list;
```

but after executing this query I received an error:

"Column 'to_do_list.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I found that LIMIT should solve my problem, but I'm getting an error after running this one:

```
Select * from to_do_list where duration = (select min(duration) from to_do_list) LIMIT 1;
```

"Incorrect syntax near 'limit'."

I'm using Microsoft SQL Express Server 2012.

I would be grateful for any help from U ppl!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error is self explanatory you are missing a `group by`. You can not aggregate without grouping by something else. You probably don't want `TOP 1` as that value is just going to be random. You need to clarify the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` does not work in SQL Server, use `TOP` instead:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM to_do_list 
WHERE duration = (SELECT MIN(duration) 
                  FROM to_do_list);
```

You can also use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY duration) RN
              FROM to_do_list)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this:

```
select top 1 *
from to_do_list t
order by t.duration
```

is preferable to

```
select top 1 *
from to_do_list t
where t.duration = select min(duration) from to_do_list )
```

Though it's worthwhile checking the execution plan to see which performs better.

Comment: Yes, it should be `order by t.duration, other_expression` to resolve the ties consistently.

Comment: @Zane: you might want to *read* the original problem statement: "I've got a table...and I want to display only ONE minimum record (where Duration = minimum), even if there are more than one." While the O.P. *might* care about selecting the specific row holding the minimum duration, he only said that he wanted **a** single row.

Comment: @NicholasCarey that doesn't mean it's not worth pointing out.